# How do I add password login to an ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication

I have two ASP.NET pages: `site.com/foo/bar.aspx` that should be world accessible and `site.com/foo/baz.aspx` that I want to password protect. I want any un-authenticated users to see a username/password page and then, once they pass that, I want them to see the real thing. I'm looking for the simplest possible solution ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx) looked good till it stated asking me to move things), even at the cost of flexibility.

What I'd love to see would be a control that does nothing if the user is authenticated and replaces "all" other controls with a login prompt if they aren't.

I'm currently the only user who will have an account so I can go with a hard coded password list for now (and I'm more or less stuck with that as I wouldn't have anywhere else to put it).

---

Using [Greg's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174563/how-do-i-add-password-login-to-an-asp-net-page/1174696#1174696) answer I was able to make individual pages password protected. Using [Joel Coehoorn's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174563/how-do-i-add-password-login-to-an-asp-net-page/1174589#1174589) [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx) I set it up to do Forms Authentication. From [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx) I'm using a custom Login logic that looks like this:

```
    Login1.Authenticate += new AuthenticateEventHandler(Login1_Authenticate);

    ...

    void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Authenticated = (Login1.UserName == "user" && 
                           Login1.Password == "password");
    }
```

All of that put together seems to work fine. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, the easiest thing is probably [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx).  You just hook everything up in your web.config file and [build a simple login page using the pre-built controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178331.aspx).

Comment: Let me guess, that;s going to require me to make a new page... I really hope that's not the simplest solution.

Comment: The "username/password page" you're asking for has to come from somewhere.  All you have to do is drop a login control on the form and you're done.

Comment: I was kinda hoping that my existing page could be both: a login page to unathenticated users, and the real thing afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a Windows network? You can just use windows authentication via the web.config if you are.

Something like this would work:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>

  <location path="page.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="domain\role"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Edit: Ok, not using windows network.  This might help you with a down&dirty single user method: http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/1772445/Setting-username-passwords-in-the-web-config-using-forms-authentication.aspx

Comment: I don't own the box and can't do anything with users.

Answer (score 1):

If you really only have one page, use a multiview.

#### ASPX page

```
<asp:MultiView ID="mvSecretContent" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="viewLogin" runat="server">
        <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="username" 
            runat="server">Username:</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="password"
            runat="server">Password:</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="login" runat="server" OnClick="login_Click" 
            Text="Log In" />
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="viewSecret" runat="server">
        <h1>This is secret information!</h1>
        <asp:Button ID="logout" runat="server" OnClick="logout_Click" 
            Text="Log Out" />
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

#### Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["IsAuthenticated"] == null || 
        !(bool)ViewState["IsAuthenticated"])
    {
        mvSecretContent.SetActiveView(viewLogin);
    }
    else
    {
        mvSecretContent.SetActiveView(viewSecret);
    }
}

protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // authenticate user/pass

    ViewState["IsAuthenticated"] = true;
}

protected void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["IsAuthenticated"] = false;
}
```

It's only stored in `ViewState`, so you'll have to re-authenticate every time you visit the page. If you change `ViewState` to `Session` it'll stick for however long your session is set up for (default is usually 20 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

This is a followup to BCS's comment on Joel's answer:

You will need to create a Login.aspx form, but it is incredibly easy: [How To: Create an ASP.NET Login Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178331.aspx)

Comment: I guess I might not get to be that lazy.