# How do I use a ASP.NET Login control without using a MembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

This is an offshoot of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174563/how-do-i-add-password-login-to-an-asp-net-page).

- How do I use a `Login` control if I don't have a `MembershipProvider` to point it at?
- Am I understanding the use model correctly?
- Is it even reasonable to talk about using a `Login` control without a `MembershipProvider`?
- Dose the `MembershipProvider` do more than just username/password checking?
- Would it be more reasonable to create my own `MembershipProvider` with the same authentication logic?

In my case, I don't need a `MembershipProvider` (I think) as my authentication situation is trivial (one user, one password).

I'm interested partly to "future proof" my page and partly because I'm new and wondering about how stuff works. (I tend to learn about things by running full speed into every corner case I can find :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just drop the asp:Login control in your page, then in the code behind, catch the Login Control's Authenticate event.

In the Authenticate event, check the username/password that the user has entered. The username/password are properties in the login control. (LoginCtrl.UserName, LoginCtrl.Password)

If the username/password is correct, just set the event args Authenticated property to True.

No membership provider is required.

ex. In the aspx page..

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginCtrl" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="YouAreIn.aspx"></asp:Login>
```

In Code Behind

```
Private Sub Log_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles LoginCtrl.Authenticate
    If LoginCtrl.UserName = "Hello" AndAlso LoginCtrl.Password = "Hello" Then
        e.Authenticated = True
    End If
```

c#

```
void MyLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if(UserName == "Hello" && Password == "Hello")
        e.Authenticated = true;
}
```

Comment: Also, to force the user to go to the login page, use forms authentication.

Comment: If only it were so easy. I just tried it and the login jumps directly back into the login page rather than the page it was redirected from.

Comment: BCS - Did you set the DestinationPageUrl?

Comment: No, but every source I've found up to now indicates that the default will be the page that redirected to the login page.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to mention to set the DestinationPageUrl to the page the user is suppose to be redirect to. I have a working sample in case you need it.

Comment: in your web.config are you denying anonymous users? 

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>  
  <allow users="*"/> 
</authorization> 

also, here's my authentication settings, just for reference. <authentication mode="Forms">  
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30"></forms>  
</authentication>

Comment: the comments don't seem to format XML properly. When you say referring page, do you mean the page the user was one to get to your login page? or the page the user was access before being prompted to login? or something else?

Comment: After fixing `web.conf` it works without setting `DestinationPageUrl`.

Comment: oh, cool, did you set the defaultUrl in the web.config instead?

Comment: Nope, it works as expected: if left unset, it goes right back to the page that redirected to `Loging.aspx` whatever that happens to be this time.

Comment: @BCS - could I get a cleaned version of this code? I'm interested in getting something like this to work (C#), but the Login control doesn't appear to have any Event Handlers like Justin wired up. Also, there seems to be a lot of the solution in the comments. I don't know what is good and what is not.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a membership provider and don't really have a security system to speak of, just put two boxes on a form (user name, password) and test it in the onclick of the button.

The login control is obviously overkill for what your trying to do.

Comment: you are probably correct... for now. Also that forces me to figure out how to deal with cookies and redirection and whatnot.

Comment: I'm not having trouble creating a cookie, I just haven't ever worked with it and would rather not have to learn right now.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx).

Comment: That might work in my case but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a custom authentication provider and plug it in via web.config.  http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256