# How to use login controls with Access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to use the login controls in Visual Studio with my Access database. I'm not sure how to use the two. Here's what I have so far:

Login.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Login" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/EditSite.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
    </asp:Login>
</asp:Content>
```

And here's the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)

        ViewState["LoginErrors"] = 0;
    }
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
         if (YourValidationFunction(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
         {
             e.Authenticated = true;
             Login1.TitleText = "Successfully Logged In";
        } else {
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }
    }

    protected void Login1_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ViewState["LoginErrors"] == null)

            ViewState["LoginErrors"] = 0;

        int ErrorCount = (int)ViewState["LoginErrors"] + 1;

        ViewState["LoginErrors"] = ErrorCount;

        if ((ErrorCount > 3) && (Login1.PasswordRecoveryUrl != string.Empty))

            Response.Redirect(Login1.PasswordRecoveryUrl);

    }

    private bool YourValidationFunction(string UserName, string Password)

    {

        bool boolReturnValue = false;

        string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TravelJoansDB.mdb;";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);

        String SQLQuery = "SELECT UserName, Password FROM Login";

        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(SQLQuery, con);


        OleDbDataReader Dr;

        con.Open();

        Dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (Dr.Read())

        {

            if ((UserName == Dr["UserName"].ToString()) & (Password == Dr["Password"].ToString()))

            {

                boolReturnValue = true;

            }

            Dr.Close();

            return boolReturnValue;

        }

        return boolReturnValue;

       }

    }
```

Here's the web config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
       <controls>
         <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
       </controls>
    </pages>
     <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
       <providers>
         <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
       </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
         <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
<!--
        If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
        you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
        change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
        of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
  -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
       <providers>
         <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
       </providers>
    </sessionState>
  <httpModules><add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" /></httpModules></system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxControlToolkit" publicKeyToken="28f01b0e84b6d53e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.40412.0" newVersion="4.1.40412.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TravelJoansBlog-20130718193109;Integrated Security=SSPI"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TravelJoansDBSQLConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DCSLAPTOP\TRAVELJOANS;Initial Catalog=TravelJoansDBSQL;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules>
    <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
  </modules>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
</system.webServer>
  <resizer>
    <plugins>
       <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
       <add name="DiskCache" />
       <add name="PrettyGifs" />
       <add name="SimpleFilters" />
    </plugins>
  </resizer>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. When I click the login button, it gives an error about not finding a network related instance. I have security set on the folder for full control for everyone.

Comment: Can you write the exact error message received?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: can you share webconfig membership and connectionstring

Comment: See my updated question. Good to see you again, Samiey.

Comment: Hey all, I decided to use a different route. I found this and was able to get it to work for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174954/how-do-i-use-a-asp-net-login-control-without-using-a-membershipprovider Thanks again fellas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a different route. I found this and was able to get it to work for me. [How do I use a ASP.NET Login control without using a MembershipProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174954/how-do-i-use-a-asp-net-login-control-without-using-a-membershipprovider)

Answer (score 1):

Login control by default use of **membership** table in **ASPNETDB.mdf** file. if you want use a custom database such as access database , you need to implement **Membership Provider**.

see following pages:

[How to: Implement a Custom Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Sample Membership Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Sample code:**
http://www.devx.com/assets/sourcecode/13854.zip