# What's the most professional way for login control in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

Say, we are not using forms authentication or membership. When a user requests for any of the pages of the application, she needs to be redirected to login page.
This way, each page needs to have an authentication check on the Page_Load(). But what if we have over 500 pages.

Any chance to use sth like static classes with static properties or creating your own http handlers?

Comment: Your `static` variable is application-wide. Once someone logs in, everyone's logged in.

Comment: Do you have more than one user?  Should one user being logged in mean that every single other person accessing the site should be considered logged in?

Comment: use your session to store if your user is logged in, assuming you can use sticky sessions..

Comment: And.. use cookies also. There are many tutorials how to provide authentication in WebForms. F.e: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I use a ASP.NET Login control without using a MembershipProvider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174954/how-do-i-use-a-asp-net-login-control-without-using-a-membershipprovider)

Comment: I logged in from a client. While I am logged in, tried to login from another client, still asked for password. I think it's not "Once someone logs in everyone's logged in"

Comment: @Juge: Learning is fine, but people (myself included) are voting for the "too broad" close reason. "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: I suppose already supplied the details. There is my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is too broad of a question with a few aspects, including** :

- How to manage a User's Session
- How to manage multiple user accounts being logged in
- How to perform the login process

Managing a user's state must be independent of anyone else's actions. Therefor, you cannot rely on static properties. This presents the question of "Well, how do I keep track of it without it being static?" One of the answers is to use Session information. For example, during an Ajax request to the server you could do this :

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedIn"] != null)
{
   object oValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedIn"];
   bool bResult;

   if (bool.TryParse((string)oValue, out bResult) == true)
      return bResult

   return false;
}
else
   return false;
```

This solves the first two issues and opens a door to creating a hanlder class that knows YOUR specific session keys and patterns for getting different kinds of values.

As for the third issue you will face - No one can give you a concrete answer. Your design and data structure will determine how you validate and track your users.

Comment: When you feel that a question is too broad and cannot be given an appropriate answer the proper course of action is to vote/flag the question for closure, not post an answer to explain why you can't answer the question.

Comment: He stated, just part of it cannot be answered. And he might have already voted for closure.

Comment: @Servy - Jude said it right. The answer provided addressed the root issue that was presented by code as well as defining what issues could not be resolved in this format while still still attempting to provide a bit of clarity for the OP to find their own solution using the answer provided. This is an adequate answer by any definition.

Comment: This is a horribly insecure, and error prone way to manage logins.  IIS can dump sessions whenever it feels like, and then suddenly you're logged out.  Sessions are also insecure, and can be easily stolen.  Doing security yourself almost always is a bad choice.

Comment: Good to know. So far it has worked for us, but we may need to add some more in depth security considerations and research to the backlog... It's exciting to be getting input back that leads to a practical application in project development. I appreciate it. I'll have to remember to come back and fix this once I've done more research